# How to Iterate Over JavaScript Object and Display results In Specified Place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, each

I have object `replies`:

```
[Object { content="Comment #1."}, Object { content="Comment #2."}]
```

And I have selector that selects place where content should be placed...

```
$('.post .comment_this[rel="3"]').parent().parent().append(encoded.content + '<br />');
```

How to iterate over that object and display results in that place one by one?

Comment: It's not an object, it's an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replies` is an array, you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
var $target = $('.post .comment_this[rel="3"]').parent().parent();

for(var i = 0, l = replies.length; i < l; i++) {
    $target.append(replies[i].content + '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Assuming

`var replies = [{ content:"Comment #1."}, { content:"Comment #2."}];`

you can use something like this [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/H7vZ6/)

```
var target = $('.post .comment_this[rel="3"]').parent().parent();
$.each(replies, function(i, reply) { target.append("<br/>"+reply.content)});
```

Comment: I think `Object` is just part Firebug's textual representation of an object. It is not valid syntax if it were like this.

Comment: Yeah, I realised when I looked closer